# My simple app closes on button click

Tags: android

The app is expected to accept two numbers, and on button click, print the sum in the textView.

The layout appears as expected as this as desired :
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K42jt.png)
But on button click, the app 'stops like this : [Stopping message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMvYa.png).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="57dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="187dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the java file is.

```
package com.example.home.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et1, et2;
    TextView tv1;
    Button bt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int num1, num2, res;

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

                res = num1 + num2;
                tv1.setText(res);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it shows the layout as desired on the mobile and also on the emulator. It also accepts the two numbers properly. But when the button is clicked, the app stops as shown. I am using Android 3.1.3.

Kindly advise where I am going wrong ?

Comment: search for the error in logcat and put it here.

Comment: Did you check the value of et1.getText() and et2.getText()?

Answer (score 0):

change this line : `tv1.setText(res);`
into this `tv1.setText(String.valueOf(res));`

Comment: Hello thank you for trying to answer, can you explain the logic behind your solution?

Comment: @JamesWong setText needs a string to set it in textView and the res is int so when you do this `String.valueOf(res)` it will return the string value of the int

Comment: Thank you all. I understood the issue and corrected it, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an integer value in textfield, which is not allowed. So you are getting an exception. In order to solve convert integer to string.

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int num1, num2, res;

         num1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
         num2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

         res = num1 + num2;
         tv1.setText("" + res);
    }
});
```

Also you should apply validation. As if user clicks the button without entering any number, the app will stop. So you should add -

```
if(! et1.getText().toString().equals("") && ! et2.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

    res = num1 + num2;
    tv1.setText("" + res);
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enter the numbers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The res variable should be String type.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is `tv1.setText(res)`. There are two methods with one parameter, which are `setText(Int) and setText(CharSequence)`. As in your code, you accidentally called the first method as you declared `res` as an Integer, which is interpreted as a resource id. You should call the second one by converting `res` to String.

Just change the line `tv1.setText(res);` to `tv1.setText(Integer.toString(res));`

```
package com.example.home.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et1, et2;
    TextView tv1;
    Button bt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int num1, num2, res;

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

                res = num1 + num2;
                tv1.setText(Integer.toString(res));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can read up the [**TextView** documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#public-methods) to learn more about its public methods.

Comment: Thanks yo for the explanation in the beginning. I recall having seen resid, and then thinking it could be something related to my variable res, selected it, feeling it will let me use an int there. Now I understand the deeper meaning.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. If that answer helped your case, please mark it as an accepted answer. I will appreciate it.